# Visual Studio 2013 and libpng

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, libpng

I'm trying to write a simple PNG file using libpng in C using VS2013. I installed libpng from Nuget and included png.h, but I can't compile. I get this as my output:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_create_write_struct referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_longjmp_fn referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_create_info_struct referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_write_info referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_destroy_write_struct referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_init_io referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_free_data referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_IHDR referenced in function writeImage
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_text referenced in function writeImage
```

I've tried playing with the compilation settings, but nothing seems to make it work. I don't get any red lines under any of those declarations when I write the code, so VS must be seeing some of the code.

Comment: VS is seeing the header file.  In the link step, you need to have something line "-Lpathtolib -llibrootname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides including `png.h` you must also link with the appropriate import library (probably called `libpng.lib` or something similar).  In Visual Studio, you would add this to *Project Settings → Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies*.

Comment: Actually in this case it's not a problem about a missing library - the idea behind NuGet is that (like `pkg-config` under Linux) the libraries to link are included automatically.  In this case the most likely problem is that the NuGet package needs to be updated for a new toolset version (so it isn't supplying any library filenames because it doesn't recognise the current toolset.)  This seems to happen when using a version of Visual Studio newer than the package.  I posted an answer at the above duplicate question with details on how to do this.